# Change all hyphens to dots in my data set in excel

Tags: excel, substitution

I have this over 1100 line data set and I want to used it in R studio, but I can't because it has hyphens. I want to change all 1100 lines from hyphen to dots eg. 1929-3 to 1929.3 Is there a formula or function to do this without manually changing them all?

I have already tried using the `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",".")` function and the Find/Replace function. What could I do?

Comment: Both options should've worked in Excel (I have tested and they work). I do not see any obvious reasons why the formula should not work.

Answer (score 2):

I did a simple "Replace All", recorded it as a macro, and this is what I got:

```
Cells.Replace What:="-", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
    , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```